# LINQ Query to return list based on attribute of DB field

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a `Conversation` class which corresponds to multiple tables in the database.
A Conversation has a list of `Users` as a field. I want to return a list of Conversations based on whether or not the `Users` field contains the parameter

I am unsure how to do this...

I know this code does not work or even compile but it should give an idea of what I am trying to do:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetConversationForUser(String email)
{

    IQueryable<Conversation> users = from d in db.Conversations
                                     where d.Users == email; // I wish to something like **d.Users.Email == email** here but I am unsure how to express this correctly

    if(users == null)
    {
       return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343630(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method:

```
 IQueryable<Conversation> users = from d in db.Conversations
                                  where d.Users.Any(u=>u.Email== email)
                                  select d;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetConversationForUser(String email)
{

    IQueryable<Conversation> users = from d in db.Conversations
                                     where d.Users.Any(u=>u.Email == email)
                                     select d; 

    //Check if the query returns something not if the query is null, which won't happen 
    if(!users.Any())
    {
       return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question right. If i got it correctly you could just write

```
var users = db.Conversations.Where(r => r.Email!= null || !r.Email.Equals(string.Empty))
```